# Why can't <some-name> be used in a python list?

Tags: python, xml, dom

For example, we can't manually enter in the list:

```
list = [<element1>, <element2>, <element3>...]
```

which throws an error:

```
>>> list = [<DOM Text node "u'\n\t'">]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    list = [<DOM Text node "u'\n\t'">]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

whereas we can put the element from the XML parse elements into a list, which doesn't cause any syntax error. I have listed some XML elements in a list:

```
[<DOM Text node "u'\n\t'">, 
 <DOM Element: APPLE at 0x18a4648>, 
 <DOM Text node "u'\n\t\n\t'">, 
 <DOM Element: GOOGLE at 0x18a4968>, 
 <DOM Text node "u'\n\t\n\t'">, 
 <DOM Element: LENOVO at 0x18a4b48>, 
 <DOM Text node "u'\n\t\n\t'">, 
 <DOM Element: SAMSUNG at 0x18a4be8>, 
 <DOM Text node "u '\n'">]
```

which works fine, but when I manually try to feed the list with above elements, it fails.

Can anyone explain why this is so?

Comment: `<DOM Text node "u'\n\t'">` is the *representation* of the node, `node.__repr__()`, it is **not** the same thing as the actual node object, which doesn't have a "literal" representation. The representation is not, in itself, valid Python syntax; hence the `SyntaxError`.

Comment: You can put any Python object into a list.  An XML parse element is a python object, what you have is invalid syntax.  You maybe want to create a string object instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is printed between the angled brackets is simply a human-readable presentation of a class, for example:

```
>>> class Test:
...  pass
... 
>>> a = Test()
>>> print(a)
<__main__.Test object at 0x7f76070b6198>
>>> repr(a)
'<__main__.Test object at 0x7f76070b6198>'
```

the `<...>` is just a string of text, we can actually control what it printed with the [`__str__()` and `__repr__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) functions:

```
>>> class Banana:
...   def __str__(self):
...     return 'I am probably yellow!'
...
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return 'I am probably yellow!'
... 
>>> b = Banana()
>>> print(b)
I am probably yellow!
>>> repr(b)
I am probably yellow!
```

If you want to create a list with these variables, then use the variable names (in this case, `a` & `b`): `list = [a, b]`

Bonus hint:
`list` is a builtin name in Python (refering to the `list` type (`type([]) == list`); you probably don't want to use this as a variable or function name (but because Python is cool, it will allow you to do so anyway).